# How to rename existing 'named configurations' using gcloud cli in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gcloud-cli

I would like to know if there is a way to rename an existing 'gcloud topic configurations' e.g. I would like rename 'foo' to 'bar' in the below example.

I couldn't find anything on this in the gcloud reference documents.

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Technically, it is not possible to change the name of that configuration using the `gcloud` command.

However, you can change it doing this little workaround:

- Use [`gcloud config configurations activate [YOUR_CONFIG_NAME]`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/configurations#Using-configurations) to activate the configuration you wish.
- Use [`gcloud info --format='get(config.paths.active_config_path)'`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/configurations#Using-configurations) to find the directory where your configurations are stored. You will get the path of the file of that specific configuration, looking like this `/tmp/tmp.XAfddVDdg/configurations/[YOUR_CONFIG_NAME]`
- If you `cd` into the directory `/tmp/tmp.XAfddVDdg/configurations/`, you will find all your configurations there. Every configuration will be named there like this `config_[YOUR_CONFIG_NAME]`. Modifying the part that matches the name of your configuration will successfully change its name. DO NOT delete the `config_` part of the name.
- After this, is you print all the configurations using `gcloud config configurations list`, you will find your configuration renamed, but none will be active now. Just activate it with `gcloud config configurations activate [YOUR_CONFIG_NAME]`, and you will be good to go.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I did shortly after asking this question with the only difference of activating another config set before renaming the one that I wanted to. This was to avoid any potential issues.

Comment: Yes, I took the same precaution, that is why I wrote the first step.

Comment: For me on Windows, the `--format` parameter doesn't work, but it's still pretty easy to pick out the file path from the resulting output. For windows users, the path should be similar to `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\configurations\config_NAME` where `USER` is your username and `NAME` is the name of the configuration.

Comment: @chunk_split On Windows you should just use double quotes instead of single quotes. Like `gcloud info --format="get(config.paths.active_config_path)"`.

Comment: More recent versions of glcoud on Linux store the configurations in `~/.config/gcloud/configurations/`.

Comment: Brennan's answer should be the chosen one in 2022.

Answer (score 6):

Don't know when this was added, but there is a `remame` command for `configurations`. So no more need to jump through hoops by deleting and recreating configurations or directly editing the file.

```
gcloud config configurations rename CONFIGURATION_NAME --new-name=NEW_NAME
```

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/configurations/rename